# How can I create a program that can receive this data in decimals?

Tags: java

How can I create a program that can receive this data in decimals?

When I run my code for example with 480.000 fail, but with 480000 works!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    String salario=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su salario, por favor");
      
    int ahorro=Integer.parseInt(salario);
    
    int resultado=(ahorro*15)/100;
    
    int ahorros=resultado*12;
     
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted ahorra mensualmente de su salario " + resultado + " Si usted ahorra el 15 porciento de su salario al lo largo del ano habra ahorrado " + ahorros);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run your code?

Comment: When I run my code for example with 480.000 fail, but with 480000 works!

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to parse an `int` from the input string, but you are inputting `480.000` which Java doesn't know how to handle because of the decimal. What you should do is remove the `.` character from the input string before you run `parseInt`. So your program should be able to change `480.000` to `480000`

Comment: Could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Double.parseDouble(salario)` or `Float.parseFloat(salario)` while convert a decimal string type to numeric type.

Try below code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    String salario= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca su salario, por favor");

    double ahorro=Double.parseDouble(salario);

    double resultado=(ahorro*15)/100;

    double ahorros=resultado*12;
    
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Usted ahorra mensualmente de su salario " + resultado + " Si usted ahorra el 15 porciento de su salario al lo largo del ano habra ahorrado " + ahorros);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int` (integer) data type, you must use `double` or `float`

```
  
    double ahorro=Double.parseDouble(salario);
    
    double resultado=(ahorro*15)/100;
    
    double ahorros=resultado*12;
```

or

```
    float ahorro=Float.parseFloat(salario);
    
    float resultado=(ahorro*15)/100;
    
    float ahorros=resultado*12;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!! and sorry, I'm new in this